# Slow XAMLX Designer - Visual Studio 2013 -Workflow Foundation

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2013, workflow-foundation-4

The VS2013 XAMLX designer is **very slow** with medium sized xaml workflows.

About 10 to 40 seconds for each small change we make.

We don't want to disable the designer and work in xaml directly.

This is what we have done and tried so far (without success)

1. Disable Resharper
2. SSD Drive to speed up I.O.
3. Make sure the machine has enough memory and cpu...

Has anyone got more ideas on how to speed this up?

**UPDATE (23-11)**

*This is a little convoluted, though it might shed some light.*

I installed VS2015, which made a huge difference, though the workflows wouldnt work in IIS. The problem was due to a windows update which caused an error. Check this link https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3118750

I was getting errors like this:

> FileLoadException: A procedure imported by 'Microsoft.VisualBasic.Activities.Compiler.dll' could not be loaded

So, I am guessing that validation was turned off while the compiler had issues. 
It seems like VS2010 had a setting to turn off validation, though I cant find how to do that in 2013

Does this help at all, can anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: Have you tried closing all **other** open XAML files in Visual Studio?

Comment: Only the one file open, Turned toolbox populate too. The xamlx file is ~500kb big.

Watching resource monitor, I see the CPU spikes, not the drive...

Comment: Nothing you can do but throw more CPU at it.

Comment: Check Jeff Atwood's latest blog post for a comparison of CPUs and single threaded performance.  As the UI thread is a single thread, cores won't help your rendering speed.  Also, WPF uses your GPU if you have one, so make sure you've got a decent vidya card. I can't say how much perf you get per $$, so you might want to research that.

Comment: This seems to have helped me (No idea why), maybe shared DLL's *shrug* Though if you are in VS2013, Simply just install a copy of VS2015, and continue to edit the workflow in VS2013. Much much faster.